# How to change/fix operator settings on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

My android studio has a problem about text editor.When i write something which includes equal operation '=' it seems as a minus operator '-'. What happened to my operator settings.

`list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` seems

```
list - (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: can u post a screenshot of how it looks? also curious about the font you are using?

Comment: Your question made my mind clean. There isn't existing equal operator 
Settings->Editor->Colors&Font -> Font  screen. I use consolas font. Today i install some font program for changing windows font like mac's font. There may be damaged some windows font file or while i was playing to change font on Android Studio i deleted something unconsciously

Comment: So if you change the font does it look ok?

Comment: Yes, But most of fonts doesn't have = operator.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to use that do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything like operator settings in Android Studio. It should have something to do with the font that you might be using.